# Pesquisa em MYSQL em campos com nomes iguais

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, estou precisando fazer uma pesquisa no mysql em que utilizo diversos inner joins, e por se tratar de relacionamentos muitos pra muitos, alguns dos campos se relacionam com mais um campo da outra tabela, segue um exemplo em que ficará mais fácil de se entender

`SELECT livros.id_livro, livros.nome, livros.caminho, categorias.nome as categoria FROM livros INNER JOIN categorizados ON categorizados.id_livro = livros.id_livro INNER JOIN categorias ON categorizados.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria WHERE categorias.nome LIKE 'Terror' AND categorias.nome LIKE 'Suspense'`

Aqui deixo em destaque o seguinte trecho: `WHERE categorias.nome LIKE 'Terror' AND categorias.nome LIKE 'Suspense'`
E é sobre ele que a dúvida está relacionada, em um dos meus livros cadastrados, tenho um que se tem duas categorias nele cadastrado, uma com nome 'Terror' e outro com nome 'Suspense'
Porém não consigo filtra esse livro com essa requisição, acredito que exista alguma forma de fazer essa requisição, porém não sei como ainda, gostaria que me ajudassem, obrigado!

Edit1: A pesquisa após o WHERE são em registros diferentes, um registro tem o campo nome como 'Terror' e o outro registro tem o campo nome como 'Suspense'

Comment: Se é que eu entendi você não deveria utilizar OR no lugar de AND já que, pelo que entendo, um campo não pode ter simultaneamente os valores 'Terror' e 'Suspense'. Pode ser que, caso queira selecionar aqueles que tem dois registros na tabela categorias você possa utilizar a cláusual GROUP BY com COUNT e a cláusula HAVING COUNT(id_categoria) > 1.

Comment: São registros diferentes, as duas tabelas estão relacionadas, e tenho dois registros, um com o campo nome como 'Terror' e outro com o campo nome como 'Suspense'

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o que deseja é algo do tipo:

```
SELECT livros.id_livro, livros.nome, livros.caminho, GROUP_CONCAT(categorias.nome SEPARATOR ';') as categoria 
FROM livros INNER JOIN categorizados ON categorizados.id_livro = livros.id_livro 
            INNER JOIN categorias ON categorizados.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria 
WHERE categorias.nome LIKE 'Terror' OR categorias.nome LIKE 'Suspense'
GROUP BY livros.id_livro
HAVING count(categorias.id_categoria) > 1
```

Comment: Manin, no where eu preciso que tenha um AND entre as duas condições, não um OR

Comment: Meu caro, se você tem em cada registro de sua tabela categorias um campo nome que contém um texto ('Terror', 'Suspense', etc) então, pelo que entendi de sua descrição, é impossível que cada registro contenha diferentes nomes, que é o significado do AND. Pelo que você descreveu não é um registro com 'Terror' **outro registro** com 'Suspense' e assim por diante?

Comment: Olhe, acredito que você não tenha compreendido o que eu quis dizer, mas o que tenho é uma tabela chamada categorias como você já deve ter notado, e dentro dela eu tenho uma coluna que se chama nome
E então eu tenho 2 registros nessa tabela, um tem dentro da coluna nome 'Terror' e o outro 'Suspense', observe que ambos compartilham a mesma tabela, e mesma coluna, mas registros diferentes, por isso a requisição de ambos é categorias.nome
E então eu tenho uma tabela (livros) que se relaciona com essa tabela através de uma intermediaria (categorizados), em resumo não é apenas 1 registro, mas 2

Comment: Perdão se eu me expressei mal antes o que tenha resultado em mal entendimento, mas é que eu ainda sou um pouco iniciante

Comment: Teste a query que apresentei e verifique se o resultado apresentado não é exatamente o que deseja. Estude a cláusula HAVING pois ela é que irá determinar os livros que estejam classificados em `Terror` **e** em `Suspense`. Utilizo `OR` porque são em registros diferentes.